# When I creating Application .h & .m files are not creating in XCode?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

When I creating Application it's creating `test.xib file`, *.h & .m files are not creating* in XCode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that type create xib file only. if you want .m and .h with xib file. you create new .m and .h file tick xib for user interface 
check box

Step 1:

[image]

Step 2:
[image]

Comment: no this window is not coming...this options are coming. I select New>File->IOS->User Interface->Application/View/etc->IPhone/IPad->inter face name. Can you tell me or update your answer post

Comment: choose options for creating new files

Comment: it works accepted my answer that means click tick mark and you also get reputation point